# ¿Cuál es la forma más adecuada de decir "ropa casual" en correcto español?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término, ropa

En el colegio donde trabaja mi esposa los profesores pueden ir los viernes con *ropa casual pero no informal* (ella entiende perfectamente la diferencia).

Algo "casual" según el diccionario es "algo que sucede por casualidad". Claramente no es posible que la ropa sea *casual*, o *fortuita*, o *accidental*. Yo me imagino que se debe a algún juego de palabras.

¿Cómo se puede entonces nombrar correctamente el estilo de vestuario que se conoce como "ropa casual"?

Comment: Según [Cambridge Online Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/casual) `Casual clothes are not formal or not suitable for special occasions`.

Comment: Es un calco del inglés, que el [DPD recomienda evitar](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=NoA02xQk1D6mtGBw8v).

Comment: Interesting distinction as I would have said casual and informal dress meant the same in English. The custom is known as dress-down Friday by the way but I am not sure that helps with a translation.

Comment: Yo enfocaría más en los errores en tu pregunta original. Primero, la palabra "mas" solo se acentuá cuando va sola. En este caso no se acentúa porque va con la palabra "adecuada." Es decir, funciona como adjetivo. Esto es prácticamente la norma con palabras monosílabas. Segundo, el decir “correcto español” simplemente suena mal. Suena como si estas traduciendo directamente de Ingles (correct Spanish). Suena mas natural el decir “Español correcto” o mejor dicho “Castellano correcto o propio” Tercero, “ropa casual” esta bien dicho. No hay razón para cambiarlo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Según mi mujer, que es la experta en estos temas, *ropa casual* se refiere a ***[ropa de diario](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DfZ8RL8)***, entendiéndose como tal a cómo te vestirías de forma arreglada para ir un día cualquiera al trabajo. Sería un punto intermedio entre vestirse de forma elegante para una ocasión formal, y un atuendo completamente informal. Entiendo que la persona a la que se le dice eso se le exige algún tipo de vestimenta obligada en el trabajo (léase un traje formal, o un uniforme), pero se le permite libertad de vestimenta un día a la semana mientras no vaya, digamos, con camiseta y bermudas.

Comment: Si, yo había pensado de diario también.